# R plotly scatter plot with color coding and error bars

Tags: r, plotly

I have `xy` data I'd like to plot using `R`'s `plotly`. The y points have an associated error, of which I'd like to plot the error bars. These points are also associated with a group of two levels.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20),y.err=runif(20,0,0.1))
```

Here, I define the group levels:

```
df$optimal <- F
df$optimal[1] <- T
df$optimal <- factor(df$optimal,levels=c(F,T))
```

And, here's my plotting code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
scatter.plot <- plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~df$optimal,x=~df$x,y=~df$y,data=df) %>%
  layout(title="TITLE",xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))
scatter.plot <- scatter.plot %>% add_trace(scatter.plot,error_y=list(value=df$y.err),data=df,showlegend=F)
```

This gives me:
[image]

As you can see, the error bar of the blue point (the optimal one) is missing.

This does not happen when I do not color by `df$optimal`:

```
scatter.plot <- plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,data=df) %>%
  layout(title="TITLE",xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))
scatter.plot <- scatter.plot %>% add_trace(scatter.plot,error_y=list(value=df$y.err),data=df,showlegend=F)
```

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: it might be a bug. The error bar is there but you just can't see it. Just hover (top graph)) that point (the optimal one) and you will see that the value for the error bar is 555.92µ which is really low. I have noticed the same kind of error on the example showed on the plotly website.